# How to check if a function has a value

Tags: php, oop

I am not sure if the title is correct, my problem is that I have a class and functions inside it, I would like to check if the value for the function is set and if not set other value

```
class some_class
{
    private $width;

    function width( $value )
    {
        // Set another default value if this is not set
        $this->width = $value;
    }
}

$v = new some_class();


// Set the value here but if I choose to leave this out I want a default value
$v->width( 150 );
```

Comment: If you're using a setter method, call it as it is: `setWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class some_class
{
    private $width;
    function width( $value=500 )  //Give default value here
    {
        $this->width = $value; 
    }
}
```

Check [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) for default value.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for

```
class some_class
{
    function width($width = 100)
    {
        echo $width;
    }
}

$sc = new some_class();

$sc->width();
// Outputs 100

$sc->width(150);
// Outputs 150
```

Comment: Is there a reason you've posted an answer already posted, while also completely changing the example the OP was using?

Comment: There is somehow a reason, I needed more than 3 minutes to create the answer. And while typing, I'm not constantly looking for other answers flying in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private $width;

    function setWidth($value = 100)
    {
        $this->width = $value;
    }
}

$object = new SomeClass();
$object->setWidth();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($object);
```

Will result into like this if empty:

```
SomeClass Object
(
    [width:SomeClass:private] => 100
)
```

or something like this too:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private $width;

    function setWidth()
    {
        $this->width = (func_num_args() > 0) ? func_get_arg(0) : 100;
    }
}

$object = new SomeClass();
$object->setWidth();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($object); // same output
```